# javascript get selected text not value

Tags: javascript, html

Is it possible to get the selected text in the `select` not its value?

```
<select id="animals">
   <option value="mammals">Elephant</option>
   <option value="reptile">Snakes</option>
   <option value="mammals">Bear</option>
   <option value="birds">Ostrich</option>
</select>
```

I want to know the type of animal that is being selected.

Thank you for all your help.

Comment: where is your javascript ?

Answer (score 4):

```
function getSelectedText(elementId) {
    var elt = document.getElementById(elementId);

    if (elt.selectedIndex == -1)
        return null;

    return elt.options[elt.selectedIndex].text;
}

var text = getSelectedText('animals');
```

Answer (score 2):

> Use [`Document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector), *Returns the first element within the document that matches the specified group of selectors.*

```js
console.log(document.querySelector('#animals option:checked').textContent);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<select id="animals">
  <option value="mammals">Elephant</option>
  <option value="reptile">Snakes</option>
  <option value="mammals">Bear</option>
  <option value="birds">Ostrich</option>
</select>
```

[**Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/ncnjaevf/)

Answer (score 0):

jQuery:

```
$("#selection option:selected").text();
```

with pure Javascript:

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].innerText
```

Try This

Comment: Where did you see `jQuery` tagged ?

Comment: Citation needed for *May be this will help you*.

Comment: While I appreciate that you're just trying to help, please stick with the technologies/tags that were specified in the original post. While your solution might very well be correct, it would require the addition of the jQuery library.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done by using javascript selectedIndex and text method.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <p>Choose an option in the drop-down list and display that option.</p>

  <form>
    <select id="mySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
      <option value="mammals">Elephant</option>
      <option value="reptile">Snakes</option>
      <option value="mammals">Bear</option>
      <option value="birds">Ostrich</option>
    </select>
  </form>

  <p id="demo"></p>

  <script>
    function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("mySelect");
      var i = x.selectedIndex;
      document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x.options[i].text;
    }
  </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem whereby I wanted to output selected text (not value) into a Textarea box. I solved it this way:

```
     <label>Objectives :</label>
<select name="objectives" class="objectives" onchange="getObjectives(this);">
<option selected="selected">--Select Objectives--</option>
<option selected="selected">--One--</option>
<option selected="selected">--Two--</option>
</select>

<textarea rows="4" cols="30" id="objid"></textarea>

<script>
function getObjectives(sel) {
// Select option returns text instead of value of option
document.getElementById ("animals").value = sel.options[sel.selectedIndex].text;

}

   </script>
```